# How to create a Server

Tags: android, server, connection

I want to create a server that can be between among a few thousand people and can play there 1v1. like quiz up app 
I've read Android documents but it does not seem to explain it.
[Building Apps with Connectivity & the Cloud](https://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html)
I'm so confused about the servers and all kind of this

need Help!

i will mark this correct for those who can answer thanks
 John

Comment: Any advice? i know this is unclear question but i need Help:(

Comment: Server programming isn't related with android programming, you can use several tecnology (php, c#, java, nodejs, and a lot more) thinki about giving a look here: https://www.codeschool.com/beginners-guide-to-web-development/server-side-languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating server you have to use any backend language like PHP will be very comfortable for beginners.
You can refer php MySQL connection with Android using *volley* or any Http connection in Android.
You can refer to www.androidhive.com and search for above for better understanding.